# Why Regex "(({12}*10)/100)".replace(new RegExp("{12}",'g'),value) not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

My following regex is not working.

```
"(({12}*10)/100)".replace(new RegExp("{12}",'g'),value)
```

I want to replace {12} with "value". It is throwing error that

Invalid regular expression: /{12}/: Nothing to repeat(…)..

What is the issue?

Answer (score 8):

You need to double escape the {} curly brackets see:

```js
var value = 50;
var result = "(({12}*10)/100)".replace(new RegExp("\\{12\\}",'g'),value);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Or better yet, use a regular expression literal: `.replace(/\{12\}/g, value)`

Comment: thanks it works. However following work as well 

(({12}*10)/100)".replace(new RegExp("{(12)}",'g'),value)

Which is better solution?

Comment: @BhaskarDabhi: `.replace(/\{12}/g, value)` is best. The `{` should be escaped as it is a special character and using `{(12)}` you make the regex engine allocate some buffer for Group 1 contents - while you are not using them.

Answer (score -2):

I got it. Following is my solution:
"(({12}*10)/100)".replace(new RegExp("{(12)}",'g'),value)

Comment: Your solution looks very weird... You basically deactivated the normal meaning of `{` and `}` by using `()` which is normally meant to **capture** something (so that you can use the value you matched).
What you should do, I think, as explained by Shekhar Khaimar, is escape the `{}` characters using `\ `.